# How to make the equilibrium double arrow longer?

Tags: mhchem

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}  

\ce{H^+ (\textit{aq}) + HCO3^- <=> H2CO3 (\textit{aq}) <=> H2O (\textit{l}) + CO2 (\textit{g})}

\ce{2H2(\textit{g}) + O2(\textit{g}) <=> 2H2O(\textit{l})}

\end{document}
```

I am new to Latex and doing some chemistry reports and while MS equation editor is a pain, it decently works even by using mixed fractions to get ion charges with subscripts for atoms, but I digress.   I cannot do the double harpoon-like symbol for chemical equilibrium "longer" as I like the arrows to be stretched out more than it is.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Welcome! Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so folk can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original version didn't work for me, hence `\expandafter`'s:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

%\ce{H^+ (\textit{aq}) + HCO3^- <=> H2CO3 (\textit{aq}) <=> H2O (\textit{l}) + CO2 (\textit{g})}

\ce{2H2( \expandafter\textit{g}) + O2( \expandafter\textit{g}) <=> 2H2O( \expandafter\textit{l})}

\ce{2H2( \expandafter\textit{ g}) + O2( \expandafter\textit{g}) <=>[\hspace{1cm}][] 2H2O( \expandafter\textit{l})}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what i am looking for.  sorry about the first one, the sample i found worked for me.  thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please use mhchem with the `version` option. You should always read the warnings you get.

Second, why do you try to get the state in italic text? IUPAC recommendation is just normal roman (= upright) text.

You can make the arrows longer by writing some 'space' above them, e.g. `\hspace{10ex}`.

Are you looking for an option to make all arrows longer by the same value? That is not yet an option available for users, but I could put it on my todo list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}  
\ce{H^+(aq) + HCO3^- <=>[\hspace{10ex}] H2CO3(aq) <=> H2O(l) + CO2(g)}

\ce{2H2(g) + O2(g) <=> 2H2O(l)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you require?

[image]

Then use the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{eqnarray*}  
H^+ (aq) + HCO3^- &\Longleftrightarrow& H2CO3 (aq) \Longleftrightarrow     H2O (l) + CO2 (g)\\
2H2(g) + O2(g) &\Longleftrightarrow& 2H2O(l)
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't even close to proper chemical typography. Look at your H2O and compare with the other solutions.

Comment: As @mhchem already noted this is wrong in quite a number of aspects: *(1)* chemically: usage of italic instead of upright font shape for atom symbols, missing subscripts, wrong kind of arrow (the arrow shapes have distinct meanings in chemistry) *(2)* typographically: missing spaces between stoichiometric factors and formulae, missing spaces between formulae and phase descriptors. *(3)* `eqnarray` is a bad choice: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196 *(4)* it doesn't actually answer the question (regarding `mhchem`'s arrows)