# Mhchem arrows length

Tags: arrows, mhchem

Is it somehow possible to change the default length of arrows in chemical reactions using 
`mhchem`? In particular I would need to reduce its length, both for single and for double (equilibrium) arrows. I ask, if possible, coherent solutions, in the sense of commands designed for this package, if they exist. I tried something like `\ce{a + b ->[-5pt] c}`, it seems to not work

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240084/how-to-make-the-equilibrium-double-arrow-longer) post says how to  make double arrow longer? Have you seen this before?

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But I need something in order to reduce it, not to make it longer

Comment: The author of `mhchem` replied and said “I am quite busy at the moment, but I will eventually implement your suggestion.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package doesn't provide a way to set the minimum arrow width, but it's possible to add it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mhchem }
 {
  arrow-min-length .code:n =
   \cs_set:Npn \__mhchem_arrow_options_minLength:n { {#1} } % default is 2em
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ce{A + B -> C}

\ce{A + B <-> C}

\ce{A + B <=> C}

\mhchemoptions{arrow-min-length=1em}

\ce{A + B -> C}

\ce{A + B <-> C}

\ce{A + B <=> C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `\mhchemoptions{arrow-min-length=1em}` in the preamble to set the length globally, or locally in some environment.

Comment: I was to the pag. 18 of `mhchem` package and I was not understood the code `\mhchemoptions{arrows=%
pgf{Kite[length=0pt 4,width’=0pt 1]}{0.15ex}}
\ce{A <--> B}`

Comment: @Sebastiano That's for changing the shape of the arrow tips.

Comment: I thought that it was the key of the solution.

Comment: This has no effect for me - if I run your code, all the arrows come out the same, long, length.

Comment: @Nathaniel I don't know what to say: I tried on a fresh document with everything updated and it works as advertised.